# Does xmlhttprequest keep connection open after request has been processed?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I have done a simple ajax...

The request and response header both contain the Connection: `Keep-Alive`

I goggle a bit and saw that the client thus maintain a persistent connection
with the server. This support pipelining, where client may send multiple request without waiting for each response.

So i have some questions:

1. Where does the xmlhttprequest actually open a connection to the server?
2. Does creating many xmlhttprequest object open their own connect or it send it on a same connection using pipelining...?
3. I want to handle simultaneous request.. Can i queue the request(store parameters) ..and in the onreadystate provide function to handle it.. i.e. calling the function that make request recursively? or it's not a good idea at all?
4. When is the connection closed..at what stage?

*Other info:*
I don't want to use jquery or any other librarie for the ajax.You can propose though. i
can check how they work.
I'm using javascrip and php(codeigniter framework).
I want to be able to handle multiple request(2)..and queue request that are
made when the limit has been reached.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you understand that http requests are accomplished by using a `tcp connection`? http uses tcp like a fax uses a phone line. `tcp connection` is what is being referred to in `Connection: Keep-Alive`. You don't really know when or where the browser decides to create a tcp connection, but generally browsers will create multiple simultaneous tcp connections to a server if it would be beneficial. requests for html, images, css, ajax requests etc... all go over the same lines(although again, the browser will generally open multiple lines).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yups i know it's take place over the Tcp connection. Thanks for the clarification about the Connection: Keep-Alive. I have read that the standard is 2 simultaneous connections, though some browsers support more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is an object which let you to request and receive data from server without refreshing the page. It uses `HTTP` or `HTTPS` requests. It is basically same as requesting and receiving an HTML page. You may open them synchronous or asynchronous.

```
XMLHttpRequest.open( Method, URL, Asynchronous, UserName, Password )
```

Here, `Method` is `HTTP` request method to use. See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method

> I want to handle simultaneous request.. Can i queue the request(store parameters) ..and in the onreadystate provide function to handle it.. i.e. calling the function that make request recursively? or it's not a good idea at all?

I'd make an array of XMLHttpRequests and handle data and remove XMLHttpRequest from array `onreadystatechange`. Keep in mind that you will receive a mixed order of asynchronous responses or may not receive a response at all.

> When is the connection closed..at what stage?

It is closed right after data is received. Note that `keep-alive` is about keeping the session alive, not the connection.

Comment: Not by me. Thanks for the reply. I'am going to check more on it.

Comment: Alan, you are welcome. I am just curious because if there is something wrong in my answer, I don't want to mislead anyone with it and I'd like to learn from my mistake.

Comment: @Ertug > "Note that keep-alive is about keeping the session alive, not the connection." Untrue. It's all about keeping the (TCP) connection alive.  There is no such thing as a "session."

Comment: @Orwellophile, depending on how you treat it, TCP is session over IP :)

Comment: @pavel_karoukin, agreed. but http is 1 or more sequential (and partially parallel) *transactions* over that tcp layer.

Comment: @pavel_karoukin Technically I would have to disagree. TCP is a transport mechanism (Layer 4) over IP, that provides a reliable connection. Setting up a new TCP connection brings overhead with it, so you want to keep it open as much as possible. A session would live right on top of a TCP connection (Layer 5) and is in general not applicable to HTTP request, since HTTP generally operates on the Application Layer (7). So, `keep_alive` is all about keeping the connection alive if possible. Just the HTTP request gets closed.